# Reading two lines from StreamReader VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, newline, streamreader, memorystream

I have a problem reading two lines from a stream reader. I want to read the first line and then proceed to the next one. Here's my code:

```
Public Function Read()
    Dim a As New MemoryStream(ASCII.GetBytes("[ID] " & vbCrLf & " salut" & vbCrLf))

    Debug.Print(client.ReadLine(a))
    Debug.Print(client.ReadLine(a))
End Function    


Public Function ReadLine(ByVal Data As MemoryStream)
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(Data)
    Return sr.ReadLine
End Function
```

The output is:

> [ID]

One line. I checked the stream in debug mod and I've seen that the position was 15 after the first ReadLine call. So I have to move the "pointer" after the first VbCrLf(that's all the way to the end). But I don't think that's the proper way of doing it. Where am I wrong? I even passed the stream by value so it should've worked.

     **EDIT**

   I made some checks and it seems that and only when passing a stream the position moves to the end. I created a stream reader in the same Read function and passed as parameter the a memory stream. It worked. I don't know why this happen. I'm still looking for an answear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you are really trying to do, but you are not really *trying to read two lines from [a] StreamReader*, you are trying to read *one* line at a time from *two different streamreaders* using the same data source/buffer.

```
Dim buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[ID] " & vbCrLf & " salut" & vbCrLf)

Using ms As New MemoryStream(buff)
    Using sr As New StreamReader(ms)
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine("memstream poition: " & ms.Position)
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine("memstream poition: " & ms.Position)
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())
    End Using
End Using
```

If you set a breakpoint on the first `sr.ReadLine()`, you'll see that the `MemoryStream` position has changed.  If you mouse over the `sr`variable, you'll see why:

[image]

`Streamreader` has a buffer, 1024 bytes by default.  You can compare that buffer to the one created in code and see they are the same.  There is also a `StreamReader` overload which allows you to specify the size:

```
Public Sub New(stream As System.IO.Stream, 
                encoding As System.Text.Encoding,
                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks As Boolean, 
                bufferSize As Integer)
```

Trying to read from a single data stream with different (new) `StreamReaders` wont work because **the previous one will have already consumed some of the data**. You should be able to read many thousands of lines into an array or list which your code can use as a line-buffer.